# How to display the FAB in all activities

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button

In my `activity_navigation.xml` I put my `FAB` here. 
The is below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/quick_apply"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/view_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/imgicon"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="View Images" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/camera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/camicon"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="Camera" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer"
    android:background="@color/tableHeader"/>
```

I set this `xml` on my `NavigationActivity` where this will be like my `BaseActivity` and then extended it to all my other `Activities`.

My problem when running the app the `FAB` is not displaying, because it has been covered by the xml I assign to the `content_frame`. But If I put the `com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu` in one of my other `activities's xml` for example in my `Home Screen` it will display it but i wonder how can I display the `FAB` without repeating it to add on my `xml`. All the action of the `FAB` I put it on my `NavigationActivity`.

Thank you for the help.

**update**
By the way I'm using the `FrameLayout` named `content_frame` to my other `activities` to display the `xml` of that `Activity` like in my `Home Screen` like this

```
FrameLayout contentFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_home, contentFrameLayout);
```

Comment: your NavigationView has height of match parent. you frame layout also height match parent, they will overlap, you try set you frame layout with 20dp height and see

Comment: @kggoh it still doesn't display :( I tried to put 20dp for layout_height in the framelayout.

Comment: @kggoh I tried to put the 20dp height in my other activities xml the fab displayed now. is there a way how to solve this? cause i need to display the content of those activities as a whole in the screen.

Comment: check the test sample i do below, try to use another xml file, test with more simple view component, see if you can see both components, you are using framelayout which will make components to overlap if you did not set the width and height correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is I create two `FrameLayout`  in my `activity_navigation.xml`

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fab:menu_icon="@drawable/quick_apply"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/view_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/imgicon"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_label="View Images" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/camicon"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_label="Camera" />

</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

</FrameLayout>
```

Where my `FAB` is not inside the `content_frame`, so that it will not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

//i do not have your resource value, so i try to make a test example, which replace your drawer view with textview. If i put framelayout height with match parent, i only see one textview, only if i put the height be 20dp, it will appear both textviews.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/content_frame">

            <TextView
                android:text="text above"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </FrameLayout>


        <TextView
            android:text="text below"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but it will not display the layout in the whole screen. :(

Comment: what do you mean. it will. the linear layout is match parent height. maybe you have to post a screen that what you are trying to achieve here

Answer (score 0):

use Fragment instant of Activity

Comment: This should be in comments rather than in answer.When you write an answer write the relevant code snippet